# SourceTree won't let me delete password

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I am in the process of deleting an account on my source tree, but whenever I attempt to delete in:

> Tools > Options > Authentication

[SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) doesn't delete the saved password. I need to delete the password as it has the incorrect details associated with the account.

OS: Windows 10

Version: 2.1.2.5

Comment: Please also specify the SourceTree version and your OS.

Comment: I have been able to fix this issue by going back a version of sourcetree, it seems the version I am on causes this issue.

Comment: Here is the related issue on the Atlassian forums: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/Cannot-delete-an-account-on-sourcetree/qaq-p/602672

Answer (score 33):

I'll add to @KyleMit answer that you can actually edit this `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Atlassian\SourceTree\passwd` file and remove only the record you want to re-enter.

Answer (score 28):

I think Atlassian is trying to prevent the same sort of thing as trying to delete a branch that has unmerged commits, in that if the account/password is actively used in any of your repositories, the UI won't let you delete it as that *could* permanently remove access if the password was forgotten.

So how do you do a **`--force` delete**?

1. First close any open instances of SourceTree
2. As [Pathfinder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49300637/1366033), pointed out, SourceTree stores some of the passwords using the **Windows Credential Manager**
3. Go to Control Panel > User Accounts > Manage Credentials > Windows Credentials
4. Find any offending passwords and remove them

   [image: Windows Credential Manager]
5. SourceTree *also* stores passwords in you Local App Data Folder in a passwd file:
6. Open Windows Explorer (<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)
7. In the address bar, go to `%LocalAppData%/Atlassian`
8. Open the Source Tree Folder and delete the only account+pasword rows or if required delete the all accounts or delete the complete `passwd` file

   [image: Delete Local File]
9. Open Source Tree and **Perform a Fetch** before doing anything else.

**Further Reading**:

- [Cannot delete an account in SourceTree](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Cannot-delete-an-account-on-sourcetree/qaq-p/602672)
- [Still unable to delete REST Saved Passwords?](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Still-unable-to-delete-REST-Saved-Passwords-in-Tools-Options/qaq-p/694831)
- [How to update HTTP(S) credentials in SourceTree](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-to-update-HTTP-S-credentials-in-sourcetree/qaq-p/297564)

Answer (score 13):

For windows:

I solved my problem by going into windows credential manager and deleting the offending sourcetree account.

This is probably a problem with program privileges, perhaps starting source tree as admin will allow it to remove entries from the windows credential manager.

Comment: Finally, someone mentioned credential manager

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I was able to resolve it by following the steps here: 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/how-to-wipe-sourcetree-preferences-412484640.html

It may be a bit of overkill, but it was the only thing that worked.